# How would I create a semaphore using an int and char array parameter?

Tags: c

Here is a snippet of the code:

```
struct 101_sem {
        int value;   // semaphore value
        int sem_id; // semaphore ID
        spinlock_t lock; // spinlock
        char key[32]; // security   key
    //Some  FIFO    queue   of  your    devising
};

#include "../../sem.h"

/* This syscall creates a new semaphore and stores the 
provided key to protect access to the semaphore. 

The integer value is used to initialize the
semaphore's value. The function returns the identifier of the created semaphore, which can be used to down and up the semaphore. */

    asmlinkage long sys_101_create(int value, char key[32])
    {
        return; 
    }
```

Comment: @abelenky yeah.

Comment: Start by learning about what regular language defines identifiers in c.